# NSNumber LoopVar++ in for loop increments by 4 instead of by 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumber

I'm quite sure that this question has a very simple answer that I should have figured out by now. Since I haven't yet done so I come to you, stack overflow hive mind.

I expected the loop below to print out the numbers from 0 to 5. Instead it prints out only 0 and 4. Why does LoopNumber++ increment my NSNumber LoopNumber by 4 instead of by 1?

```
NSNumber *LoopNumber;
for (LoopNumber=0; LoopNumber<=5; LoopNumber++) {
    NSLog(@"%d",LoopNumber);
}
```

If I change it to the following it works exactly as I expect. What gives?

```
for (int LoopNumber=0; LoopNumber<=5; LoopNumber++) {
```

I'm fooling around with an iPhone project in XCode 3.2.1, using SDK 3.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an NSNumber is not an integer.  It is an object wrapper for a number which may be an integer.

The variable LoopNumber is actually a pointer to the location in memory where the object should be.  All LoopNumber itself holds is a memory address, which on your machine is 4 bytes long.  When you do LoopNumber++ you are inzoking pointer aritmatic on the pointer and it is advancing to the next memory address which is four bytes later.  You can see this by doing a sizeof(LoopNumber) - that would return 4 on your system.

What you really want to do is use a regular integer like so:

```
NSUInteger loopNumber;
for(loopNumber = 0; loopNumber <= 5; loopNumber++) {
  NSLog(@"%d",loopnumber);
}
```

or if you really need to use NSNumbers:

```
NSNumber loopNumber;
for(loopNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; [loopNumber intValue] <= 5; loopNumber=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[loopNumber intValue]++]) {
  NSLog(@"%d",loopnumber);
}
```

Comment: note that NSUInteger is actually a #define for a 'unsigned int', so you could use that instead, or a 'int' if you prefer, as the signedness wont matter for small numbers.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Your answer really helped me clear up my misunderstanding of NSNumber. Although I realized that NSNumber was a complex type I mistakenly thought that it would be used as a basic integer by objective c when it evaluted for loop. Too much time in perl. : - ). I also really appreciated your tone in answering a basic question to a very novice objective-C developer. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Dan Carlson: I think the thing that surprises people the most about Objective-C is just how little magic there really is. It's such a straightforward language that you almost feel like there has to be something you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

int is native type. NSNumber is a Objective-C class. Use float or int  when doing real work. But to put a int into a collection you can create an NSNumber object from the int or float native type.